# Will this patent be granted?

Tags: patentability

Motorola filed a patent application for an electronic tatoo that allows communication with a mobile device (if I get it right).

[Patent link](http://appft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&p=1&u=/netahtml/PTO/search-bool.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&co1=AND&d=PG01&s1=13462881&OS=13462881&RS=13462881)

Does a patent not require a functional prototype? So did they actually tatoo a guy to prove the concept?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A functional prototype is *not* needed. On the other hand, an application must provide everything someone skilled in the field needs to make and use the invention without undue experimentation. In the "unpredictable arts" like biology it is usually required to have done experiments.